# How to merge two different sized data frames without repeating cases of smaller data frame, in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames, both of which share a common ID variable. However, one has over 1000 observations, while the other has around 100. Below is an example of what they look like.

```
    df1 = data.frame(Id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), Type1 = 
    c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,4,NA,NA), Type2= c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,4,NA,NA))

    #df1
    # Id Type1 Type2
    # 1     1     1
    # 1    NA    NA
    # 1    NA    NA
    # 2     2     2
    # 2    NA    NA
    # 2    NA    NA
    # 3     4     4
    # 3    NA    NA
    # 3    NA    NA



    df2 = data.frame(Id = c(1,2,3), Othertypes = c(5,4,6))


    #df2
    # Id Othertypes
    #   1          5
    #   2          4
    #   3          6
```

When merging, the cases in `df12$Othertypes` from the shorter data frame (df2) are repeated, as such:

```
     df12 <- merge(df1,df2, by ="Id")

    #df12
    # Id Type1 Type2 Othertypes
    # 1     1     1          5
    # 1    NA    NA          5
    # 1    NA    NA          5
    # 2     2     2          4
    # 2    NA    NA          4
    # 2    NA    NA          4
    # 3     4     4          6
    # 3    NA    NA          6
    # 3    NA    NA          6
```

However, what I really want is 1 "Othertypes" case per Id, as such:

```
    #df12
    # Id Type1 Type2 Othertypes
    # 1     1     1          5
    # 1    NA    NA          NA
    # 1    NA    NA          NA
    # 2     2     2          4
    # 2    NA    NA          NA
    # 2    NA    NA          NA
    # 3     4     4          6
    # 3    NA    NA          NA
    # 3    NA    NA          NA
```

I have tried the following alternatives:

```
    temp <- merge(df1,df2, by="Id",sort=FALSE)
    temp2 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "Id")
```

As well as played around with `data.table` (very unsuccessfully), and with functions using `plyr` (also unsuccessful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method using `match`, `*`, `[`, and a little NA magic.

```
df1$others <- df2$Othertypes[match(df1$Id, df2$Id)] * NA^is.na(df1$Type1)
```

`match` returns the position of the first argument that match the second argument. With `[` df$Othertypes is repeated according to the positional output of `match`, so `df2$Othertypes[match(df1$Id, df2$Id)]` would return the vector that you are getting with `merge`. Now, this vector is multiplied by `NA^is.na(df1$Type1)` which returns an NA when `df1$Type1` is NA and a 1 when it is not.

This returns

```
df1
  Id Type1 Type2 others
1  1     1     1      5
2  1    NA    NA     NA
3  1    NA    NA     NA
4  2     2     2      4
5  2    NA    NA     NA
6  2    NA    NA     NA
7  3     4     4      6
8  3    NA    NA     NA
9  3    NA    NA     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rbind`:

```
df1 = data.frame(Id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), Type1 = 
                   c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,4,NA,NA), Type2= c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,4,NA,NA))

df2 = data.frame(Id = c(1,2,3), Othertypes = c(5,4,6))

df1$Othertypes<-NA
df2$Type1<-NA
df2$Type2<-NA

rbind(df1,df2)

   Id Type1 Type2 Othertypes
1   1     1     1         NA
2   1    NA    NA         NA
3   1    NA    NA         NA
4   2     2     2         NA
5   2    NA    NA         NA
6   2    NA    NA         NA
7   3     4     4         NA
8   3    NA    NA         NA
9   3    NA    NA         NA
10  1    NA    NA          5
11  2    NA    NA          4
12  3    NA    NA          6
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, because all IDs must have a value for "Othertypes". In this case, Ids 1-9 don't have any value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df1 = data.frame(Id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 Type1 = c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,4,NA,NA), 
                 Type2 = c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,4,NA,NA))
df2 = data.frame(Id = c(1,2,3), Othertypes = c(5,4,6))

df12 = merge(df1,df2, by="Id")
df12$Othertypes = ifelse(!duplicated(df12$Othertypes), df12$Othertypes, NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for this is to insert "Type1" column in df2 also and then merge by both columns as follows:

```
a<-df1$Type1
a<-a[is.na(a)]

df2$Type1<-a

df12 <- merge(df1,df2, by =c("Id","Type1"),all.x=T)
df12
#  Id Type1 Type2 Othertypes
#1  1     1     1          5
#2  1    NA    NA         NA
#3  1    NA    NA         NA
#4  2     2     2          4
#5  2    NA    NA         NA
#6  2    NA    NA         NA
#7  3     4     4          6
#8  3    NA    NA         NA
#9  3    NA    NA         NA
```